# Below=of is not understood for tikz positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use TikZ, but relative positioning of the nodes is not being understood.  I am using the MacTex installation that I downloaded today.  This code is copied from the TikZ manual, but fails to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
 transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]

 \node[place] (waiting) {};
  \node[place] (critical) [below=of waiting] {};
\end{tikzpicture}


  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Always include a caption before the label}
  \label{fig:MergeIdeal}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile with `pdflatex -halt-on-error problem.tex`, I get this output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./problem.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))

<... many more files opened...>

! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of' (in 'of waiting').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15   \node[place] (critical) [below=of waiting]
                                                  {};
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on problem.log.
```

Tikz.sty is copyright 2006, so I might have an old version that does not support this syntax, so I downloaded the latest version from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/, which is from 2013.  That gives the same error (and I did check that tikz.sty is loaded from the new location).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need the positioning library: add to the preamble `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Comment: That fixes it.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: `tikz.sty` is just a wrapper. It doesn't need to change much ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `positioning` library; add to the preamble `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
 transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]

 \node[place] (waiting) {};
  \node[place] (critical) [below=of waiting] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:MergeIdeal}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: The real code had a caption.  I removed it while making the sample simple and to be sure there wasn't any non-public info in the example.

Comment: @TroyDaniels Ah, that is good to know. Would it then be OK if you edit your question to add a "dummy" caption so I can also delete my final comment?